# Passing a C++ class instance into a C++ class on boost.python C++

Tags: python, c++, boost

I'm actually trying to use a C++ class like an attribute of an other C++ class in a Boost python library. I want to bind this two class in python like this :

```
import ClassParameter
t = ClassParameter.Slave("hi")
a = ClassParameter.Master()
a.setSlave(t)
```

Then i'd like to use some method from my Master class that use an instance of my Slave class : a.setSlave(t)
Problem is, when I bind the Slave, the Master got only a copy of the instance. And I don't know how I can do the link between both.
This is my boost code :

```
#include <boost/python.hpp>
#include "Master.h"
#include "Slave.h"
BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(ClassParameter)
{
    using namespace boost::python;
    class_<Slave>("Slave")
    .def(init<>())
    .def(init<std::string>())
    .def("getMessage", &Slave::getMessage)
    .def("setMessage", &Slave::setMessage);

    class_<Master>("Master")
    .def(init<>())
    .def(init<Slave>())
    .def("showMessage",&Master::showMessage)
    .def("setSlave",&Master::setSlave)
    .def("getSlave",&Master::getSlave);
}
```

This is my class Slave :

```
#ifndef _SLAVE_H_
#define _SLAVE_H_
#include <iostream>
class Slave
{
public:
    Slave(std::string message);
    Slave();
    Slave(const Slave& s1 );
    std::string getMessage(void) ;
    void setMessage(std::string message);
private:
    std::string m_message;
};

#endif //_SLAVE_H_


Slave::Slave(){
    m_message = "no message";
}

Slave::Slave(std::string message){
    m_message = message;
}


Slave::Slave(const Slave& s1 ){
    m_message = s1.m_message;
}

 std::string  Slave::getMessage(void)  {
    return m_message;
}

void Slave::setMessage(std::string message){
    m_message = message;
}
```

This is my Master Class:

```
#ifndef _MASTER_H_
#define _MASTER_H_
#include "Slave.h"
#include <iostream>
class Master
{
public:

    Master();
    Master(Slave s) : m_slave(&s) {}
    void showMessage();
    void setSlave(Slave s);
    Slave getSlave();


private:

    Slave *m_slave;


};
#endif //_MASTER_H_
#include "Master.h"

Master::Master(){
    m_slave =0;
}

void Master::showMessage(){

    if (m_slave!=0) std::cout<< ( m_slave->getMessage() )<<std::endl;
}

void Master::setSlave(Slave s){
    m_slave = &s;
}

Slave Master::getSlave(){
    return *m_slave;
}
```

The error message when i'm using showMessage from Master is :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 13, in <module>
    a.showMessage()
RuntimeError: basic_string::_M_construct null not valid
```

I think it's because the setSlave got a temp copy, but i don't know an other way to solve this problem.

Comment: `void (Slave s);` Forget Python. Calling this method involves making a copy. That's how C++ works. You need setSlave to accept a reference or a pointer.

Comment: Okay but if I write `void (Slave& s)`  I got this python error  :
undefined symbol: _ZN6Master8setSlaveE5Slave
Segmentation fault (core dumped).

Comment: You didn't rebuild it properly. By the way getSlave returns a copy too. You need to decide if you want copy semantics or reference semantics for the Slave class.